# Is there a way to detect from inside a package that MiKTeX is used?

Tags: conditionals, miktex, distributions

Is there a way to detect that the MiKTeX TeX LaTeX executable is used?
Something like `\ifmiktex` or even `\IfFileExists{<some file only present in MiKTeX>}{}{}`?

The reason is that in one of my packages I have to re-execute LaTeX internally on an different .tex file, which of course requires the shell escape aka. write18 feature to be enabled by the user. However, I want to support this feature recursively, i.e. the other .tex file can itself call an own LaTeX sub-process. For this to work I have to add the correct command line option to the internally call of the (`pdf`)`latex` executable.
Now this option is `-shell-escape` for TeXLive, but `--enable-write18` for MiKTeX.

Here some example code how I plan to implement this feature. The missing part is the definition of `\ifmiktex`.

```
\ifpdf
   \def\latexcmd{pdflatex }%
\else
   \def\latexcmd{latex }%  
\fi

\ifmiktex
   \immediate\write18{\latexcmd --enable-write18 \options \file}%
\else
   \immediate\write18{\latexcmd -shell-escape \options \file}%
\fi
```

Comment: MiKTeX should also understand `-shell-escape` if I am right at 2.8. Did you test it?

Comment: @Herbert: I still have an old MikTeX 2.4 and it also understands `-shell-escape`.

Comment: @Herbert, honestly no, not yet. I first need to install Windows again on one of my computers ... I had a look at the official list of MikTeX command line arguments and there the support of `-shell-escape` wasn't mentioned.

Comment: would passing both options to pdflatex do any harm?

Comment: @Martin H: Good idea. A quick test with TeXLive under Ubuntu Linux shows that it works. Also, TeXLive seems to accept `--enable-write18` as well!

Comment: @Herbert, although your comment is not the “real answer” to the question, it solves Martin's problem. Could you then post it as an answer?

Comment: @Juan, @Herbert: I'm going to test `-shell-escape` it with a new version of MikTeX as soon I find time. I also have now an idea how we might be able to define the `\ifmiktex` directive.

Comment: @Juan: I did it

Comment: @Martin: you should drop Christian Schenk a line if he could define a `\def\pdfmiktex{1}` in the MikTeX specific pdftex/luatex/context.

Comment: @Herbert: Yes, or a trivial `ifmiktex` package would be possible which is just `\let\ifmiktex\iffalse` by default but `\let\ifmiktex\iftrue` in the MikTeX installation.

Comment: @Martin, yes also a good idea. I also thought of something like `pdflatex "\ifmiktex...\else...\fi \input{...}"`

Comment: @Martin: can you try what the output of a `pdflatex` run with a MikTeX is, when you use `\pdftexbanner` in the documents body part? I have no MiKTeX running

Comment: @Herbert: The output is "This is MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.3962 (1.40.11)" with a freshly installed MiKTeX.

Comment: @Martin: then you can use this to test if you are in MiKTeX or TeXLive

Comment: @Martin: can you please test my code which I added to the answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MiKTeX supports both optional arguments `--enable-write18` and also `--shell-escape`

a possible Test for MiKTeX

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifMiKTeX
\makeatletter
\def\testMiKTeX{\expandafter\testMiKTeX@i\pdftexbanner\@nil}
\def\testMiKTeX@i#1(#2)#3\@nil{\testMiKTeX@ii#2..\@nil}
\def\testMiKTeX@ii#1.#2.#3\@nil{\ifx\relax#2\relax\else\MiKTeXtrue\fi}
\makeatother
\testMiKTeX

\begin{document}

\ifMiKTeX we use MiK\TeX \else we use \TeX Live\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: The resulting text is "we use MiKTeX". Note that there is a `\@nil` missing at the end of the parameter text of `\testMiKTeX@ii`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this way. I'm going to build on it and might publish the results later.

Comment: While `-shell-escape` works fine with both TeX Live (under Linux and Windows) and MiKTeX, the required quotes used in the `\write18` call may be different (e.g. think `\write18{pdflatex -jobname '<name>' '<file>'}` I used single quotes which do not work with MiKTeX, but with TeX Live under Windows. However, if I use double quotes per default then file names with spaces are no longer supported. If I assume only filenames and other input without spaces than this isn't a problem, but I like to support as much as possible.

Answer (score 7):

Here a general proof-of-concept solution which provides `\ifmiktex` and `\iftexlive` switches. It is based on Herberts suggestion to use the output of `\pdftexbanner`.
Once finished, it could be published as, say `ifdist` package or similar.

Please note that the `\pdftexbanner` expands to text with catcode "other", therefore `\@onlevel@sanitze` is used to also give the macro parameter text the same catcode.

---

#### Update 2012/05/05:

Reworked and tested the code for Tex Live Linux, TeX Live Windows and MiKTeX.
Provided warning for XeLaTeX which is not supported. I put it in the form of a package. Will Robertson might integrate it into `ifplatform`.

```
\ProvidesPackage{ifdistro}[2012/05/05 v1.0 Provides if-switches for MiKTeX and TeX Live]

\newif\ifmiktex
\newif\iftexlive

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\def\MiKTeX{MiKTeX}
\@onelevel@sanitize\MiKTeX
\def\TeXLive{TeX Live}
\@onelevel@sanitize\TeXLive
\def\WebIIC{Web2C}
\@onelevel@sanitize\WebIIC

% Test if \pdftexbanner exists, which is the case for latex, pdflatex and lualatex
% but not xelatex.
\expandafter\ifx\csname pdftexbanner\endcsname\relax
    \PackageWarning{ifdistro}
        {Primitive \string\pdftexbanner\space not found!\MessageBreak
         Switches \expandafter\string\csname ifmiktex\endcsname\space 
         and \expandafter\string\csname iftexlive\endcsname\space 
         will not be set\@gobble}% gobbles the "on line X" part
\else

% Scans for 'MiKTeX' string with catcode 12 (other)
\expandafter\def\expandafter\testmiktex\expandafter#\expandafter1\MiKTeX#2\relax{%
        \ifx\empty#2\empty
             \global\miktexfalse
        \else
             \global\miktextrue
        \fi
}
\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\testmiktex\expandafter\pdftexbanner\MiKTeX\relax\relax
\ifmiktex\else
% Scans for 'TeX Live' string with catcode 12 (other)
\expandafter\def\expandafter\testtexlive\expandafter#\expandafter1\TeXLive#2\relax{%
        \ifx\empty#2\empty
             \global\texlivefalse
        \else
             \global\texlivetrue
        \fi
}
\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\testtexlive\expandafter\pdftexbanner\TeXLive\relax\relax
\iftexlive\else
% Scans for 'Web2C' string with catcode 12 (other)
% This string is used by TeX Live under MS Windows
\expandafter\def\expandafter\testtexlive\expandafter#\expandafter1\WebIIC#2\relax{%
        \ifx\empty#2\empty
             \global\texlivefalse
        \else
             \global\texlivetrue
        \fi
}
\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\testtexlive\expandafter\pdftexbanner\TeXLive\relax\relax
\fi\fi

\fi

\endgroup
```

Comment: Looks good! Would it make sense to incorporate this inside ifplatform.sty? I'd be happy to add you as an author to the package if you like.

Comment: It won't work for XeTeX though.

Comment: @Will: I also think `ifplatform` would be a good place. However, I like to extract the version number as well. Give me some time to refine it first.

Comment: @WillRobertson: I found myself in need again for this. I didn't do any work on it since last time, but might rework it now. For XeTeX it would be possible to scan the first line of the log file.

Comment: For some reason TeX Live does use `Web2C 2011` not `TeX Live 2011` under Windows.

Comment: MikTeX comes in two version, 32bit and 64bit. The latter does not have biber executable. So it would be nice also to have a check for x64 version of MikTeX.

Answer (score 0):

One good approach is to test whether a particular application exist or not. For example, if Yap (dvi viewer of MiKTeX) exists, you know that you are using MiKTeX. This approach has a good advantage that works with any other engine but the disadvantage is that write18 should be enabled.

Comment: you can have MiKTeX _and_ TeXLive installed on the same machine and you can use Yap for TeXlive and ...

Comment: I just gave an example. Of course, you can make it much smarter by considering various possibilities!