# Generating 2d barcodes

Tags: barcodes

Is there any package that generates 2d barcodes (QR code). I want to add a barcode on the front page of a manual I have written containing the URL where to download that manual. It would be nice if I could continue using pdflatex. Instead of converting each time.

EDIT: [Reaction to Jake's answer]

Is it possible one could only add one barcode. I've analyzed how this works. I think the compiler runs two times, one time rendering the pstricks images. A second time inserting the images in the LaTeX pdf. However if I add two different barcodes. It simply overides the file by the last barcode, and uses this file for both the barcodes. Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: This [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1429/latex-package-to-generate-qr-codes) might be of some help. The answers seem to use pstricks though.

Comment: Indeed, but there it only compiles to .ps files. Of course one could write a simple bash script always converting the .ps file to a .pdf, but I was looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: If you include the package `auto-pst-pdf`, you don't need to go through the conversion step. See my answer.

Comment: run it with xetex and you do not need the `auto-pst-pdf` package

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will work directly with `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
  \begin{pspicture}(0.7in,0.7in)
    \psbarcode{http://www.ctan.org}{}{qrcode}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using this solution results in compiling without errors, but also without barcode. Is there perhaps a potential conflict between one of those packages? babel, amsmath, fullpage, amssymb, amsfonts, index, textcomp, graphicx, tikz, algorithm, algorithmic, wasysym, subfigure?

Comment: @CommuSoft: You need to run `pdflatex` with the `-shell-escapre` option, so that `auto-pst-pdf` can run the postscript tools.

Comment: @CommuSoft: I don't have most of those packages installed on my system, so I don't know if there's a conflict. Try commenting the `\usepackage` lines one after the other until you find the offending package.

Comment: @martin Scharrer: that indeed did the job. The option to activate was `--shell-escape` (Linux/Ubuntu 10.10). Thanks. @Jake: I've try to find a conflict but none found.

Comment: @CummuSoft: Sorry for the typo in my last comment. The manual says `-shell-escape` with one dash, but two are also accepted without error. It's a little confusing, because long options must normally have to dashes. TeXLive even accepts [the MikTeX option](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9792/2975).

Comment: The correct bounding box size is `(0.7in,0.7in)`. the bar code has this default size.

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks, I've changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: Is it possible one could only add one barcode. I've analyzed how this works. I think the compiler runs two times, one time rendering the pstricks images. A second time inserting the images in the LaTeX pdf. However if I add two different barcodes. It simply overides the file by the last barcode, and uses this file for both the barcodes. Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: @CommuSoft: one pspicture environment - one image. It is not possible that they are overwritten. Give a complete example of what you did.

Comment: @Herbert: I simply wrote\begin{pspicture}(0.7in,0.7in}\psbarcode{http://www.ctan.org}{}{qrcode}\end{pspicture} and any further \begin{pspicture}(0.7in,0.7in)\psbarcode{http://www.google.com}{}{qrcode}\end{pspicture} after compiling there was one file created by ps named file-pics.pdf. It only contained one page (barcode). Of course the expected result is two files or two pages in the same pdf.

Comment: @CommuSoft: see my answer, I have no problem. If you have one then give a _complete_ example, as I already wrote!

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at possible [packages for typesetting of barcodes](http://ctan.org/topic/barcode) at CTAN.

Answer (score 6):

Two barcode side by side, run with `pdflatex -shell-escape <file>`

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0.7in,0.7in)
\psbarcode{ctan.org}{}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}
%
\begin{pspicture}(0.7in,0.7in)
\psbarcode{tug.org}{}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]