# `pdflatex -shell-escape <file>` and \psbarcode from pst-barcode

Tags: pst-barcode

I use `pdflatex` and I am interested in using `\psbarcode` from `\usepackage{pst-barcode}`. I think I found the answer in the last post  [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10584/generating-2d-barcodes) but the explanation starts with `run pdflatex -shell-escape <file>` How and where to do this? Could you please give me an example with some file name and file extension. I suppose I have to write .tex? I work on Windows 7. I use TeXnicCenter.

Comment: which editor do you use?

Comment: for TeXnicCenter you'll find her what to do: http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pdf/pdfoutput#TXC However, the easiest way is to use `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`

Answer (score 2):

It is better to separate codes to generate diagrams from the main TeX input file. Here I put the code to generate barcode in a single separate file called `mybarcode.tex` for example.

```
%compile it with xelatex or the combo sequence latex-dvips-ps2pdf
%it is mybarcode.tex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\usepackage[tightpage,active]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=0pt
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}


\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](1.49,1.49)% I got this value by inspection (zooming up to 1000%)
    \psbarcode{tug.org}{}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Compiling `mybarcode.tex` with `xelatex` or `latex-dvips-ps2pdf`, you will get `mybarcode.pdf` as follows:

[image]

From within your main TeX input file, you can import the PDF using `\includegraphics[scale=2]{mybarcode}` macro provided by [graphicx](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx).

Comment: for `xelatex` there is no need for loading `preview` and `pspicture` is already defined as a preview environment. However, using `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}` simplifies the whole setting.

Comment: `preview` is _not_ needed for PSTricks, it does only the cropping in this case

Comment: using `auto-pst-pdf` does it all.

Comment: it loads `pst-pdf` and that package uses `preview`

Comment: for the PostScript part `latex` and for the document that program what the user started, `pdflatex` or `xelatex`