# Detecting which version of the LaTeX format is in use

Tags: tex-core, conditionals

`ltxcmds` provides `\ltx@ifpackagelater`, `\ltx@ifclasslater`, `\ltx@iffilelater`
and there is `\@ifpackagelater` - but is there any "if TeX later" or some other way to (automatically) get the used TeX version (besides looking into the log file etc., of course)?
After the comment of Joseph Wright I now know that I wanted to know the LaTeX format (not the TeX) version. (And he already gave the answer to this question).
Cool: At tex.stackexchanges answers are provided to people who do not even know their question!

Comment: Some more context might be useful. For example, are you wanting to check for features added to the engine, or for bug fixes? Versioning in TeX engines is somewhat more complicated than for LaTeX packages.

Comment: @Joseph Wright: On the one hand it's general curiosity, on the other hand the latest TeX update changed some things (see http://dante.ctan.org/get/macros/latex/doc/ltnews20.pdf ) and by redefinition of \enddocument broke some packages.

Comment: Ah, you don't mean the TeX version at all, you mean the LaTeX format version. This is stored in the macro `\fmtversion`. I suspect the breakage you refer to is to do with option lists: there was a bug report a couple of days ago about an internal macro, `\@in`, that is relevant here.

Comment: @Joseph Wright: Thanks! Sorry for confusing TeX and LaTeX format version - but I'm always learning additional things here. If you turn your last comment into an answer, I'll accept that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since version 2020-10-01 the LaTeX kernel provides the command `\IfFormatAtLeastTF{<date>}{<true code>}{<false code>}` which executes `<true code>` if the LaTeX version is `<date>` or newer and `<false code>` otherwise. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\IfFormatAtLeastTF{2021/06/01}{%
  \newcommand\VersionInfo{This document was compiled using \LaTeX\ version 2021-06-01 or newer.}%
}{%
  \newcommand\VersionInfo{This document was compiled using a \LaTeX\ version older than 2021-06-01.}%
}

\begin{document}

\VersionInfo

\end{document}
```

Furthermore, similar commands `\IfClassAtLeastTF{<class name>}{<date>}{<true code>}{<false code>}` and `\IfPackageAtLeastTF{<package name>}{<date>}{<true code>}{<false code>}` are provided for class and package tests.

Note that these three commands do not exist in LaTeX versions older than 2020-10-01. You have to keep this in mind when writing code that may be compiled with older LaTeX versions. In this case, you can e. g. add

```
\providecommand\IfFormatAtLeastTF{\@ifl@t@r\fmtversion}
```

to define `\IfFormatAtLeastTF` if necessary, or test the existence of `\IfFormatAtLeastTF` (e. g. via `\ifcsname` or `\@ifundefined`) and then execute code depending on whether `\IfFormatAtLeastTF` exists or not.

Answer (score 9):

Recent versions of pdfTeX, and I think all versions of XeTeX and LuaTeX, provide 'version' data for the engine. Something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifluatex,ifxetex}
\makeatletter
\def\engineversion@#1#2.{%
  \ifnum#2>9\relax
    #1.#2.%
  \else
    0.#1#2.%  
  \fi
}
\def\engineversion@@#1#2#3{#1.#2#3}
\edef\engineversion{%
  \ifxetex
    XeTeX:\the\XeTeXversion\XeTeXrevision
  \else
    \ifluatex
      LuaTeX:\expandafter\engineversion@\the\luatexversion.\luatexrevision
    \else
      pdfTeX:\expandafter\engineversion@@\the\pdftexversion.\pdftexrevision
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\show\engineversion
```

will show it in a 'nice' way. What this warns you about is that telling what engine version is in use also means worrying about *which* engine is in use. Without more context, it's hard to be sure quite what effect is required. One possible approach is something like

```
\def\@ifpdftexlater#1{%
  \ifxetex
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else
    \ifluatex
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \else
      \ifnum#1>\pdftexversion
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondoftwo
      \else
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
          \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
% Use cases
\@ifpdftexlater{150}{\TRUE}{\FALSE} % TRUE on my system
\@ifpdftexlater{150}{\TRUE}{\FALSE} % FALSE on my system
```

which tests the major pdfTeX version, and is TRUE for any major version greater or equal to the given argument, and FALSE for older versions or for the wrong engine begin used. (This needs the `ifluatex` and `ifxetex` packages.) Tests for minor revision is a bit more complex, but the same approach applies.

If you actually want the TeX version, then the banner or similar is the only way to go. Knuth did not provide a `\texversion` macro, and while it's possible to tell TeX2 from TeX3, that is not much use (as TeX3 was released in 1982!).

Answer (score 9):

(Second answer, as it seems the question was not really about TeX version.)

The LaTeX format version is stored in the macro `\fmtversion`. LaTeX does not provide a direct interface to do a date test on this, but it not too hard to put one together:

```
\newcommand*\@iflatexlater{\@ifl@t@r\fmtversion}
```

This is used

```
\@iflatexlater{2001/09/01}{\TRUE}{\FALSE} % TRUE, I hope!
\@iflatexlater{2011/09/01}{\TRUE}{\FALSE} % FALSE
```

Comment: Additional info: After compiling a TeX file with pdflatex, in the log file it is written "`LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2`", where it is LaTeX2e = `\fmtname`, 2015/01/01 = `\fmtversion`, and 2 = `\patch@level`.

Answer (score 6):

If you use `pdftex` in either PDF or DVI mode (i.e. `pdflatex` or `latex` with a modern LaTeX) you could adapt Herbert's answer to my question
[Is there a way to detect from inside a package that MiKTeX is used?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9792/is-there-a-way-to-detect-from-inside-a-package-that-miktex-is-used/10021#10021) to extract the TeX version instead.

It uses the primitive `\pdftexbanner` which prints something like:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011) kpathsea version 6.0.1
```

The `3.1415926` is the TeX version and can be extracted as shown in the above link. However, this wouldn't work, in general, with a very old TeX where `pdftex` isn't used in DVI mode.