# How can I programmatically populate a PDF's pdfcreator field?

Tags: hyperref, pdf, automation, metadata

As I understand it, embedding (as metadata) the typesetting engine that was used to produce a PDF document is good practice.
Here is an example of how this can be done using the `hyperref` package:

```
\hypersetup{pdfcreator={pdflatex 1.40.14}}
```

However, hardcoding this information is error-prone. What if, between now and the final version of my document, I decide to switch typesetting engine, or what if a new version gets released, and I forget to update the metadata?

If possible, I'd like to avoid hardcoding the typesetting engine (name and version) used... Is there an easy way of accessing that information during a run of that engine on my `tex` file?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26178/detecting-which-version-of-the-latex-format-is-in-use

Comment: In fact, `\pdftexbanner` may solve your whole problem...? Though it is a bit more verbose than desired, perhaps.

Comment: @cslstr Thanks; the question (and its answers) you link to is interesting. It doesn't completely answer my question, though. I'd like to format the string as in my example.

Comment: @Jubobs: `pdflatex` is a mixup of pdfTeX and LaTeX, both have version numbers, e.g. `1.40.15` and `2014/05/01`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## pdfTeX

The TeX compiler pdfTeX already sets some keys as default:

```
/Producer (pdfTeX-1.40.15)
/Creator (TeX)
/CreationDate (D:20140506215840+02'00')
/ModDate (D:20140506215840+02'00')
/Trapped /False
/PTEX.Fullbanner (This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) kpathsea version 6.2.0)
```

Some of these entries can be overwritten via `\pdfinfo` or via `\hypersetup` if `hyperref` is loaded. A nice feature of pdfTeX is, that if it detects the setting of standard keys in `\pdfinfo`, then pdfTeX suppresses its setting to
avoid duplicate keys in the same dictionary with different values. Therefore it
is possible for the user or `hyperref` to override the setting of pdfTeX.

The default of `hyperref`'s values are (line breaks added for better readability):

```
/Author()
/Title()
/Subject()
/Creator(LaTeX with hyperref package)
/Producer(pdfTeX-1.40.15)
/Keywords()
```

Also the other entries can be set by `hyperref` (`pdfcreationdate`, `pdfmoddate`, ...)

### Version number of pdfTeX

Since the version number scheme of pdfTeX has changed in the past, the algorithm for the versions specification is quite complex, from `hpdftex.def`:

```
\def\@pdfproducer{pdfTeX}%
\ifx\eTeXversion\@undefined
\else
  \ifx\eTeXversion\relax
  \else
    \ifnum\eTeXversion>0 %
      \def\@pdfproducer{pdfeTeX}%
    \fi
  \fi
\fi
\ifx\pdftexversion\@undefined
\else
  \ifnum\pdftexversion<100 %
    \edef\@pdfproducer{%
      \@pdfproducer
      \the\pdftexversion.\pdftexrevision
    }%
  \else
    \ifnum\pdftexversion<130 %
      \edef\@pdfproducer{%
        \@pdfproducer-%
        \expandafter\@car\the\pdftexversion\@empty\@nil.%
        \expandafter\@cdr\the\pdftexversion\@empty\@nil
        \pdftexrevision
      }%
    \else
      \ifnum\pdftexversion<140 %
      \else
        \def\@pdfproducer{pdfTeX}%
      \fi
      \edef\@pdfproducer{%
        \@pdfproducer-%
        \expandafter\@car\the\pdftexversion\@empty\@nil.%
        \expandafter\@cdr\the\pdftexversion\@empty\@nil.%
        \pdftexrevision
      }%
    \fi
  \fi
\fi
```

## Other drivers

Package `hyperref` also sets information entries with the other drives. But it can happen, that the driver insists of its setting for some of the keys (`/Creator`, ...).

Comment: Aaah... thanks for that. So far, I had always hardcoded this info using `\hypersetup`; I hadn't realised pdfTeX already fills the relevant fields exactly as desired. Thanks again.

Answer (score 9):

`\pdftexbanner` (introduced in pdfTeX 1.20a; see the [pdfTeX user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/pdftex/manual/pdftex-a.pdf)) produces the output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/W32TeX) kpathsea version 6.1.1
```

and contains the version of pdfTeX being used to process the document. You can extract just the pdfTex version using the following:

```
\makeatletter
\def\extractpdftexversion#1-#2-#3 #4\@nil{#3}
\edef\pdftexversion{\expandafter\extractpdftexversion\pdftexbanner\@nil}
\makeatother
```

Here `\extractpdftexversion` expects an argument text of the form `<stuffA>-<stuffB>-<stuffC> <stuffD>\@nil`, and only returns `<stuffC>` (that is, the text delimited on the left by `-` and on the right by a space  ). You can add it to your PDF document properties using

```
\pdfinfo{
  /Producer (pdfTeX \pdftexversion)
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\extractpdftexversion#1-#2-#3 #4\@nil{#3}
\edef\pdftexversion{\expandafter\extractpdftexversion\pdftexbanner\@nil}
\makeatother
\pdfinfo{
  /Producer (pdfTeX \pdftexversion)
}
\begin{document}
\pdftexbanner
\end{document}
```

No explicit need to use [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) (see [Is `hyperref` really the best way to add metadata to a TeX file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5958/5764)).

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution applicable to many engines

This solution will work independent of the typesetting engine (tested on PdfLaTeX and LuaTeX) and uses the banner string.

It uses the `xstring` package. The metadata is set in the preamble using the `hyperref` package (alternatively, you could also use the facilities provided by the `pdfx`, or `hyperxmp` packages. `pdfx` internally uses the low-level metadata setting facilities provided by the `xmpincl` package.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
% uncomment one of the two lines below suitably
% \StrBetween{\luatexbanner}{\detokenize{n }}{\detokenize{.0 (}}[\luatexversionused] % obtain luatex version used. Uncomment for luatex
% \StrBetween{\pdftexbanner}{\detokenize{n }}{\detokenize{.0 (}}[\luatexversionused] % obtain pdftex version used. Uncomment for pdftex
\usepackage{hyperref}
% uncomment one of the two lines below suitably
% \hypersetup{pdfcreator = {LuaTeX \luatexversionused} % for luatex
% \hypersetup{pdfcreator = {pdfTeX \pdftexversionused} % for pdftex
\begin{document}
blah blah....
\end{document}
```