# Conditional based on the version of pdflatex?

Tags: pdftex, conditionals

I would like to do this:

```
\pdfsuppresswarningpagegroup=1
```

However, this feature is only supported by pdftex 1.40.15 and higher. How can I do this conditionally, so that my document won't be broken in other tex engines or in earlier versions of pdftex?

As a side issue, does this command go in the preamble? (I can't test it because I'm not yet running 1.40.15+.)

Related: [Can't silence a pdftex "PDF inclusion: multiple PDFs with page group" error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183149/cant-silence-a-pdftex-pdf-inclusion-multiple-pdfs-with-page-group-error)

Comment: According to the docs, it was introduced in 1.40.14 :-)

Comment: See [How can I programmatically populate a PDF's pdfcreator field?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175717/5764) for some detail on conditioning based on the version of pdfTeX.

Comment: @JosephWright `pdftex-a.pdf` says 1.40.14, but `NEWS` says 1.40.15. Anyway I would not check for the version, but for the feature instead.

Comment: I have 1.40.14, and the feature is not present in my version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Of course, the version number can be checked, but it is not so trivial, because the numbering scheme has changed in the past several times. I think, it is easier to check for the feature, whether `\pdfsuppresswarningpagegroup` is defined:

```
\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\ifx\csname pdfsuppresswarningpagegroup\endcsname\relax
\else
  \pdfsuppresswarningpagegroup=1\relax
\fi
```

`\csname` has the side effect, that it defines an undefined command with the
meaning of `\relax`. Therefore `\ifx` with `\csname` is executed inside
a local group.

`\pdfsuppresswarningpagegroup` should then be set before it is used. Therefore the preamble is a good place for it.

Comment: +1 Someone is perfectionist here :p I would simply do `\begingroup\expandafter\ifx\csname pdfsuppresswarningpagegroup\endcsname\relax\else\global\pdfsuppresswarningpagegroup=1\relax\fi\endgroup`