# How to make code conditional on LaTeX kernel version

Tags: conditionals, latex-base

I want to make use of some kernel features introduced in the latest release (`2021-11-15`) in a package. In order to maintain some backwards compatibility, I want to issue a warning and use a workaround if the package is used with an older version of the kernel. How can I check if the kernel version is older than this release and execute code in accordance?

Comment: Searching around https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13304/which-package-version-am-i-using is related ... for this one there's `\IfFormatAtLeastTF` I guess? Didn't try

Comment: [tex core - Detecting which version of the LaTeX format is in use - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26178/detecting-which-version-of-the-latex-format-is-in-use/569709#569709) – wait, the kernel and the format is not the same thing...? Or is it? I forgot

Comment: @user202729 In my understanding they are the same. Thanks for the link, that's what I was looking for.