# Undefined control sequence \IfFormatAtLeastTF

Tags: errors

I am using `\RequirePackage{expkv/expkv-opt,expkv/expkv-def}` in my `sty` file.  But when I run my `tex` file I am getting the following error.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.

Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo))
(/home/Opstk/vulcan-kmpj/gungadin.sty
(/home/Opstk/vulcan-kmpj/expkv/expkv-opt
.sty
/home/Opstk/vulcan-kmpj/expkv/expkv-opt.
sty:34: Undefined control sequence.
l.34 \IfFormatAtLeastTF
                       {2021/05/01}
? 
/home/Opstk/vulcan-kmpj/expkv/expkv-opt.
sty:34: Emergency stop.
l.34 \IfFormatAtLeastTF
                       {2021/05/01}
/home/Opstk/vulcan-kmpj/expkv/expkv-opt.
sty:34:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on fredholm.log.
/usr/local/bin/texi2dvi: pdflatex exited with bad status, quitting.

Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Tue Apr 26 13:13:19
```

Comment: You omitted the part of the log which would have given  the answer, the latex version banner given at the start of every run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your TeX installation.

The `\IfFormatAtLeastTF` built-in was introduced for the [October 2020 release](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/569709/119). That you have an undefined control sequence means that you are running on an older kernel.

The package you are trying to load wants at least the May 2021 release of TeX to work. Your installation is too old.

Comment: Or you can add `\providecommand\IfFormatAtLeastTF{\@ifl@t@r\fmtversion}` to the document. It is recommended that package authors add this to their package before using `\IfFormatAtLeastTF` if they want compatibility with older LaTeX releases (at least for some time, until LaTeX releases older than 2020-10-01 are nearly extinct)

Comment: Am also getting a problem with `\DeclareRelease`.

Comment: Same comment as above; but `\DeclareRelease` was introduced in **2017**. So you have a **very** old TeX kernel running. You absolutely should update your TeX installation to something significantly more current. @Ephram Are you actually using a TeX installation from 2015 ish?

Comment: Quite right. I have `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex) restricted \write18 enabled.`

Comment: @Ephram It's usually not advised to pull package from different versions.  That's not at all guaranteed to work.  I'd suggest updating your TeX distribution

Comment: I got the latest texlive but get the warning that `The installation requires 7336M of disk space but only 809M is available.`.  How do I use a different installation location?

Comment: You may want to ask a different question. And when you do, please do specify your platform (operating system) and how you are installing TeXLive. (I cannot help you since I install it through my OS's package manager.)

Comment: I used to do the same, with the OS's package manager.  But my distribution in quite old now.