# Check release date of LaTeX distribution

Tags: macros, renewcommand

When, automatically, documentation some code the LaTeX output gives me the,logical, warning:

```
Package: fixltx2e 2016/12/29 v2.1a fixes to LaTeX (obsolete)
Applying: [2015/01/01] Old fixltx2e package on input line 46.


Package fixltx2e Warning: fixltx2e is not required with releases after 2015
(fixltx2e)                All fixes are now in the LaTeX kernel.
(fixltx2e)                See the latexrelease package for details.

Already applied: [0000/00/00] Old fixltx2e package on input line 53.
```

So in my own case I could just leave out the line:

```
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
```

but this would give some problems for people that (unfortunately) still use an old version of LaTeX.

I found in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/569709/44119:

> Since version 2020-10-01 the LaTeX kernel provides the command `\IfFormatAtLeastTF{<date>}{<true code>}{<false code>}`

but this gives of course the same problems as this only exists after the 2020 release.

I also found https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26229/44119:

```
\newcommand*\@iflatexlater{\@ifl@t@r\fmtversion}
\@iflatexlater{2001/09/01}{\TRUE}{\FALSE}
```

and applying this as:

```
  \newcommand*\@iflatexlater{\@ifl@t@r\fmtversion}
  \@iflatexlater{2016/01/01}{}{\usepackage{fixltx2e}}
```

gives me the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \@ already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.15   \newcommand*\@i
                      flatexlater{\@ifl@t@r\fmtversion}
?
! Emergency stop.
 ...

l.15   \newcommand*\@i
                      flatexlater{\@ifl@t@r\fmtversion}
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Normally on this site it is usual to create a MWE though I hope the information provided here is already sufficient to give a pointer to a solution.

Comment: well you are missing \makeatletter (and you naturally can simply use `\@ifl@t@r\fmtversion{2001/09/01}{true}{false}`, no need to define a macro for this).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks this works (actually I'm a bit embarrassed that I didn't think about it myself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last version doesn't work because you need `\makeatletter` to use `@` in command names.  The recommended way is to define:

```latex
\makeatletter
\providecommand\IfFormatAtLeastTF{\@ifl@t@r\fmtversion}
\makeatother
```

then use `\IfFormatAtLeastTF` throughout.  `\providecommand` will only define the command if it doesn't exist yet, which is exactly what you want.

---

If you are writing a package or class, I wouldn't advise you to support LaTeX versions older than 3 or 4 years.  TeXLive 2015 is *old*, and there is really no reason to use it nowadays:  back then, support for older versions was important because (mainly) of Overleaf and arXiv, but both now use recent enough distributions.

Comment: I agree that versions older than3 or 4 versions shouldn't be supported anymore although a lot of people and companies (!) use computers with older versions of different programs and only update when it cannot be avoided (so they could use still use a bit older versions of LaTeX, though 8 years is already again a longer time).

Comment: I don't get the usage of `\provideCommand` as I just want to use a package when a distribution is old.

Comment: The `\providecommand` line provides you the definition of `\IfFormatAtLeastTF` if the LaTeX format you are running doesn't have it.  After that definition you can write `\IfFormatAtLeastTF{2015/01/01}{}{\usepackage{fixltx2e}}` (didn't check the date).

Comment: Makes sense thanks