# Check if compiled using MiKTeX or TeX Live?

Tags: conditionals, texlive, miktex, distributions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to detect from inside a package that MikTeX is used?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9792/is-there-a-way-to-detect-from-inside-a-package-that-miktex-is-used)

We have multiple people writing on the same project. Since some of us are TeX Livers and other MiKTeXers, I was curious if there was some way to check within a TeX file, with which LaTeX/pdfLaTeX distribution one is compiling? I have been fairly successful using `ifplatform` to remove some issues between Linux and Windows compilations, but am still facing some problems between MiKTeX and TeX Live.

Although, in my opinion a cross platform and cross TeX system compatible compilation may be a bit over the top...

Comment: Does [Is there a way to detect from inside a package that MikTeX is used?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9792) answer your question?

Comment: As linked by @Qrrbrbirlbel, you can test whether `\pdftexbanner` contains `MiKTeX` or `TeX Live`. Martin's answer discusses detection of both.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for. Thanks!