# Is there a macro telling which OS we're using?

Tags: compiling, conditionals, automation, distributions, ifplatform

I got some LaTeX documents that I have to compile them under different TeX Live, such as MacTeX or TeX Live. But in different OS, the font seems different too, for example, while in Windows, I prefer to use `Cambria`, but in Mac, I like `Lucida Grande` more.

Is there was a macro to differentiate between OS?

---

***Answer Update***

As the accepted answer, We need to add more comments on this question, As I read the [package manual](http://get-software.net/macros/latex/contrib/ifplatform/ifplatform.pdf), we need more settings to use these macros:

```
% packages we need
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\usepackage{ifplatform}
```

Then we use these macros like that

```
\ifwindows
% add settings
\fi
\iflinux
% add settings
\fi
\ifmacosx
% add settings
\fi % This needs to be \fi, not \if
```

now, it works well, the point is you need more packages not only `ifplatform`.

one more thing, compile your tex file with option `-shell-escape` is required:

```
xelatex -shell-escape file.tex
```

Comment: Related question, which doesn't provide a way for detecting MacTeX though: [Is there a way to detect from inside a package that MikTeX is used?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9792)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

the `ifplatform` package provides `\ifwindows`, `\iflinux`, `\ifmacosx` and `\ifcygwin` conditionals.  i would think that would be enough; the package requires shell escape to be enabled.

Comment: I like how Cygwin is strange enough it counts as a separate OS.

Comment: @Canageek Cymwin 'looks like' *nix, but Windows is 'around'. From memory, there were various requests to be able to differentiate Cygwin from Linux (and of course from Mac OS X, OpenBSD, ...).

Comment: Cygwin is not a question, just do jobs in Windows.

Comment: Note that for `\ifwindows` shell escape is not needed, only for the other OSes. So without shell escape you can detect Windows vs. non-Windows (but not which kind of non-Windows).