# Getting started with latex and conditional typeset

Tags: conditionals, ifthenelse

I'm new to latex and really do not master its dialect and concepts...sorry inadvance.

I came to it because I need to create documents that will look different based on the targeted audience.

To be more concrete I want to generate procedure to send to customers. Depending on wether the customer have a windows or a linux environment, the procedure will obviously be different.
I've seen that latex has some conditionals but I can't understand how to implement what I need. I was thinking I could somehow set a document metadata (e.g targetSystem: linux or windows) and later you a condition to choose which section should be included in the doc and which should not.

If I had to write it in code, it would be something like:

> if (target == linux) {
>       "some text"
>   } else {
>       "some other text"
>   }

Expect I don't know what "target" could be in a latex document.

Any guidance?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please keep in mind, that thi isen't an forum. What is your specific problem/question? Latex will generate a pdf.

Comment: My question is "how do I use conditionals in order to make a section or a paragraph appear in the rendered document based on a property I can set prior to rendering"

Comment: I edited the question to try to make it more clear...

Comment: This doesn't answer your question at all, but I wouldn't generate different versions. Include the different instructions in the same document. Your client might be a company running different operating systems.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84652/is-there-a-macro-telling-which-os-were-using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditionals in LaTeX. The following shows a really basic example on how to use conditionals

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifislinux % define new flag
\islinuxfalse    % No Linux system
%\islinuxtrue    % Linux system

\begin{document}
    \ifislinux Hello Linux\else Hello Window\fi
\end{document}
```

Try to toggle the comment out on `\islinuxtrue` and `\islinuxfalse` and see what happens. Note that you have to toggle the flag manually. It doesn't detect the running OS.

You might have a look at `etoolbox` or similar packages which give a lot more control about conditionals.