# Detecting currently running executable - and usage of Latex?

Tags: macros

Somewhat in the similar vein as [Getting Texlive version in pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205210/getting-texlive-version-in-pdflatex), now I want to obtain the currently running executable inside a *tex run.

Thanks to [Write18: capturing shell (script) output as command/variable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16790/write18-capturing-shell-script-output-as-command-variable/16794#16794), I can run a shell command and obtain the output with `-shell-escape`. So, if we're on a Unix/Linux system, first we can try and see what gets reported for `echo $0` (note: the below apparently must be typed/pasted as a single line):

`pdflatex -shell-escape '\documentclass{minimal}  \begingroup\makeatletter\endlinechar=\m@ne\everyeof{\noexpand} \edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand\TeXcmdout{\@@input|"echo $0" }}\x  \begin{document} \typeout{>>is: \TeXcmdout} \end{document}'`

This produces:

```
>>is: sh
```

So, `pdflatex` on my system runs the `dash` shell upon the `\@@input` pipe. So, we can now try inspecting the parent process ID (`$PPID`) of this shell; say by running `cat /proc/$PPID/status | grep Name` in that shell:

`pdflatex -shell-escape '\documentclass{minimal}  \begingroup\makeatletter\endlinechar=\m@ne\everyeof{\noexpand} \edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand\TeXcmdout{\@@input|"cat /proc/$PPID/status | grep Name" }}\x  \begin{document} \typeout{>>is: \TeXcmdout} \end{document}'`

This produces:

```
>>is: Name: pdflatex
```

So, if I use write18 (`-shell-escape`), and a Linux shell, and am willing to run some system commands, I can find the currently running executable. However, I'd like to *not* run `-shell-escape`, and I'd preferably like a cross-platform solution.

As from the first link (and [Is there a way to detect from inside a package that MiKTeX is used?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9792/is-there-a-way-to-detect-from-inside-a-package-that-miktex-is-used/10073#10073)), one could hope that `\pdftexbanner` could be used. So, first I try the following test for printouts, written in a `bash` shell:

```bash
for iprog in {tex,pdftex,luatex,xetex,httex,latex,pdflatex,lualatex,xelatex,htlatex}; do \
 echo "## >>$iprog<<"; \
 $iprog "\nonstopmode \
   \immediate\write0{>> Testing terminal printout...} \
   \end"; \
 done
```

Note that `htlatex` will call `tex` at least two times. The problem here is that this code runs "properly" for the TeX-based engines, e.g. I'm getting for `pdftex` this in terminal:

```
## >>pdftex<<
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode

>> Testing terminal printout...
No pages of output.
Transcript written on texput.log.
```

... and I'm getting some error shown in the output for LaTeX based engines, like `pdflatex`:

```
## >>pdflatex<<
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 25 languages loaded.

>> Testing terminal printout...
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...e0{>> Testing terminal printout...}    \end

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on texput.log.
```

Nothing serious in this case; but: I guess, an `\end` takes an argument in Latex (and is a "standalone" primitive in TeX), and a `\stop` there would have taken care of this error -- but then, a `\stop`, being a Latex macro, wouldn't be understood by Tex, so I'd get an error there.

This made me think - it would probably be useful to have a variable or switch that would inform whether the currently running engine is Latex-based or not; so I'll use this opportunity to ask if there is something like that out there?

Anyways, getting back to the `\pdftexbanner` - we can stick it in the above shell code loop:

```bash
for iprog in {tex,pdftex,luatex,xetex,httex,latex,pdflatex,lualatex,xelatex,htlatex}; do \
 echo "## >>$iprog<<"; \
 $iprog "\nonstopmode \
   \immediate\write0{>> is: \pdftexbanner} \
   \end"; \
 done
```

and see what we get; the code works for `pdftex`, `luatex`, `latex`, `pdflatex`, `lualatex`; but for `tex`, `xetex`, `xelatex`, I get:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<write> >> is: \pdftexbanner 

<inserted text> 
                }\endwrite 
<*> ...    \immediate\write0{>> is: \pdftexbanner}
                                                      \end
>> is: 
(see the transcript file for additional information)
No pages of output.
Transcript written on texput.log.
```

... that is (as mentioned in above posts), `\pdftexbanner` does not exist for these engines.

So, my question would be - is there anything out there, that can be used to determine the currently running executable of a *tex run, without resorting to `write18` explicit queries to a shell?

Comment: [iftex](http://ctan.org/pkg/iftex) can distinguish pdfTeX/XeTeX/LuaTeX/none-of-the-above. But I'm not really certain how you want to distinguish TeX from LaTeX (which is not like distinguishing different engines - these are distinctions of different kinds). Note that e.g. `pdflatex` is just a symbolic link to `pdftex` on Unix-type systems, at least. When you parse `ps`, for example, you are getting the name under which the executable is called. But it is the same executable.

Comment: Thanks for that @cfr - I have used `iftex` before, but I completely forgot about it in this context :) I found a nice usage example for `iftex` here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44694/fontenc-vs-inputenc/44701#44701 ... As far as the Latex macros go, I can see in new TexLive 2014 the executable banner emits "`preloaded format=pdflatex`" or "`preloaded format=pdftex`", but I don't think it's (yet) available from within a document... Cheers!

Comment: But within a document you surely know whether you are using TeX or LaTeX, don't you?

Answer (score 2):

If your supervising environment (*e.g.* the shell script running TeX) knows which TeX program it runs, just let it write this information in a file that your TeX macros can read.

If you are running a UNIX system, you can quickly write wrappers around TeX programs which do this for you.